# JS library load error in shinyapp digital ocean

Tags: digital-ocean, shiny-server, shiny, rhandsontable

I have deployed my shinyapp over digital ocean.  I use the rhandsontable among other libraries.  Since yesterday,  I am seeing the following error on my browser console:

Wed Jun 15 2016 21:11:08 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time): Connection opened. http://example.com/Main/TerminalNG2/
http://example.com/Main/TerminalNG2/handsontable-0.24.3/handsontable.full.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://example.com/Main/TerminalNG2/rhandsontable-0.3.1/rhandsontable.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Please help me resolve the issue
Regards,
SD

Comment: Are those files at the specified location?

Comment: I believe so as I used below code to install those packages  sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('rhandsontable', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""